# GridBagConstraints not placing components at the written coordinates

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

please have a look at this image below:
[image]

As you can see **"Add Program" , "Delete Program" , "Add New Unit" and "Delete Unit"** are overlapping the buttons that come before.

The buttons that come before are placed at (0,9) and the stated buttons are at (0,10).

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class guiStyle extends JFrame
{       
    Container cp = getContentPane();

    public guiStyle()
    {
        super( "Student Study Planner 2014" );
        makeFrame2();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public void makeFrame2()
    {                                
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension ( 1000 , 600 ) );

        cp.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets ( 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 );

        JLabel lblProgram , lblUnit , lblDetails;        
        JList programList , unitList;
        JTextArea pl = new JTextArea("ProgramList" , 20 , 20);
        JTextArea ul = new JTextArea("UnitList" , 20 , 20);
        JScrollPane sp , sp2;


        JButton btnAddProgram , btnDelProgram;
        JButton btnAddUnit2Prog,btnDelUnitFromProgram;

        JButton btnAddUnit, btnDelUnit;
        JButton btnAddPrere,btnDelPrere;
        JButton btnAddCoreq,btnDelCoreq;

        lblProgram = new JLabel ( "Program" );   
        lblUnit = new JLabel ( "Unit" );

        programList = new JList();        

        unitList = new JList();        

        btnAddProgram = new JButton ( "Add Program" );
        btnDelProgram = new JButton ( "Delete Program" );
        btnAddUnit2Prog=new JButton ( "Add Unit To Program" );
        btnDelUnitFromProgram=new JButton("Delete Unit From Program");

        btnAddUnit = new JButton ("Add New Unit");
        btnDelUnit = new JButton ("Delete Unit");
        btnAddPrere = new JButton("Add Prerequisite");
        btnDelPrere = new JButton("Delete Prerequisite");
        btnAddCoreq = new JButton("Add Corequisite");
        btnDelCoreq = new JButton("Delete Corequisite");

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2 ;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cp.add ( lblProgram , gbc );

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight= 7;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        cp.add ( pl , gbc );

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add ( btnAddProgram );
        p1.add ( btnDelProgram );
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 9;
        cp.add ( p1 , gbc );


        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add ( btnAddUnit2Prog );
        p2.add ( btnDelUnitFromProgram );
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        cp.add ( p2 , gbc );


       //Unit
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2 ;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        cp.add ( lblUnit , gbc );       

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridheight= 7;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        cp.add ( ul , gbc );        

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.add ( btnAddUnit );
        p3.add ( btnDelUnit );
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 9;
        cp.add ( p3 , gbc );

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.add ( btnAddPrere );
        p4.add ( btnDelPrere );
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.gridy = 10;
        cp.add ( p4 , gbc );

    }

}
```

What could have cause this misdisplay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the panels are using the properties supplied to them from the what you earlier set, for example...

```
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 2;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
gbc.gridheight = 7;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
cp.add(pl, gbc);

JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.add(btnAddProgram);
p1.add(btnDelProgram);
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 9;
cp.add(p1, gbc);
```

You set the `fill`, `gridwidth` and `gridheight` properties for `pl`, but only change the `gridx` and `gridy` for `p1`, which means it's still using the same `gridheight` properties.\

If you reset the `gridheight` property to `1`, you should be able solve the problem...

```
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.MAGENTA));
p1.add(btnAddProgram);
p1.add(btnDelProgram);
gbc.gridheight = 1;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 9;
cp.add(p1, gbc);
```

(I added the color borders so I see what I was doing)

[image: Layout]

Also,

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
```

Isn't going to do what you think, you might want to use

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Instead...

Comment: Thanks for the reply and answer! :) Learnt something new again :D